# How $x^3 + x + y^3 + 3y = 6$ becomes $3x^2 + 1 + 3y^2(dy/dx) + 3(dy/dx) = 0$

Tags: calculus

Please show how $x^3 + x + y^3 + 3y = 6$

becomes $3x^2 + 1 + 3y^2 \frac{dy}{dx} + 3 \frac{dy}{dx} = 0$

My reasoning, using Thompson's useful dodge, the chain rule, is as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
x^3 + x + y^3 + 3y &= 6 \\
u + y^3 + 3y &= 6 \\
u &= x^3 + x \\
u &= -y^3 - 3y - 6 \\
y^3 + 3y &= 6 - u \\
(y + dy)^3 + (y + dy) &= 6 - (u + du) \\
y^3 + 3y^2dy + 3ydy^2 + dy^3 + 3(y + dy) &= 6 - (u + du) \\
y^3 + 3y^2dy + 3y + 3dy &= - (u + du) \\
3y^2dy + dy &= du \\
dy(3y^2 + 1) &= du \\
\frac{dy}{du} &= \frac{1}{3y^2 + 1} \\
\\
(u + du) &= (x + dx)^3 + (x + dx) \\
(u + du) &= x^3 + 3x^2dx + 3xdx^2 + dx^3 + x + dx \\
(u + du) &= x^3 + 3x^2dx + x + dx \\
du &= 3x^2dx + dx \\
du &= dx(3x^2 + 1) \\
\frac{du}{dx} &= 3x^2 + 1 \\
\\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{dy}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dx} \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{1}{3y^2 + 1} \cdot (3x^2 + 1) \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{3x^2 + 1}{3y^2 + 1} \\
\end{align*}
$$

This does not result in `3x^2 + 1 + 3y^2(dy/dx) + 3(dy/dx) = 0`

^1 Calculus Made Easy. 1998. *Thompson, S. and Gardner, M.* St. Martin's Press

Comment: Tip: do NOT manipulate the equation. Just start with the original equation and differentiate it.

Answer (score 2):

If you assume that $y = y(x)$, you can simply differentiate the initial expression to get
$$
(x^3+x+y(x)^3+3y(x))'= 6' \Rightarrow 3x^2+1+3 y'(x) y(x)^2+3y'(x)= 0
$$

Introducing the new variable $u$ is pointless in this case... and prone to error. Solving with respect to $y'(x)$, you have that
$$
y'(x)(3y(x)^2+3) = -1-3x^2 \Rightarrow y'(x)=-\dfrac{1+3x^2}{3+3y(x)^2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$x^3 + x + y^3 + 3y = 6$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\big(x^3 + x + y^3 + 3y\big)=\frac{d}{dx}(6)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\big(x^3 + x + y^3 + 3y\big)=\frac{d}{dx}(x^3)+\frac{d}{dx}(x)+\frac{d}{dx}(y^3)+\frac{d}{dx}(3y)=\frac{d}{dx}(6)$$
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{d}{dx}(x^3)=x^2\\
\frac{d}{dx}(x)=1\\
\frac{d}{dx}(y^3)=3y^2\frac{dy}{dx}\\
\frac{d}{dx}(3y)=3\frac{dy}{dx}\\
\frac{d}{dx}(6)=0
\end{cases}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\big(x^3 + x + y^3 + 3y\big)=x^2+1+3y^2\frac{dy}{dx}+3\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way which is not recommended to be memorized:

If $F(x,y)=c$, where $c$ is a constant, is an implicit representation of the function $y=y(x)$ and $F(x,y)$ has continuous first partial derivatives then
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}}$$
In OP, it is given that $F(x,y)=x^3+x+y^3+3y$ and $c=6$. So, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=3x^2+1$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=3y^2+3$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{3x^2+1}{3y^2+3}.$